# c# RestSharp odata.nextLink JSON response

Tags: c#, json, odata, restsharp

I am still new to C# and API's in general. I've had no issues with this API until yesterday when I realized I wasn't getting all the data I was expecting in my response.

What I am trying to do is call this API link to get the JSON response then convert it to XML and save the document, which works perfect but there is a page-size limit on this endpoint.

There is a **odata.nextLink** in the response but I don't know how to use it.

What I have tried is "Searching" the response for the text string "odata.nextLink". I was able to search for that string and it gave me the value that I needed but I couldn't figure out how to use it in a do-while loop to append the data from each response.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Here is the code I am using (Access_Token blocked out for security reasons)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using RestSharp;

namespace GetProducts
{
    public class WebRequestGet
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://api.channeladvisor.com/v1/Products?access_token=*******************&$select=Sku,ID&$count=true");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            var content = response.Content;

            string json = content;

            XmlDocument doc = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json, "Channeladvisor");

            doc.Save(@"C:\Users\NHead\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\GetProducts\GetProducts\bin\Debug\Response.xml");

            Console.WriteLine(content);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the response I get before it gets converted to XML.

```
{
  "@odata.context":"https://api.channeladvisor.com/v1/$metadata#Products(Sku,ID)","@odata.count":10728,"value":[
    {
      "Sku":"650SheetSets-P","ID":4932487
    },{
      "Sku":"400SheetSets-P","ID":4932488
    },{
      "Sku":"1500SheetSets-P","ID":4932489
    },{
      "Sku":"650TWSH SL WH","ID":4932510
    },{
      "Sku":"650TWSH SL BL","ID":4932511
    },{
      "Sku":"650TWSH SL GD","ID":4932512
    },{
      "Sku":"650TWSH SL MDBL","ID":4932513
    },{
      "Sku":"650TWSH SL IV","ID":4932514
    },{
      "Sku":"650TWSH SL BGY","ID":4932515
    },{
      "Sku":"650TWSH SL SKBL","ID":4932516
    },{
      "Sku":"650TWSH SL CHC","ID":4932517
    },{
      "Sku":"650TWSH SL SG","ID":4932518
    },{
      "Sku":"650TWSH SL TP","ID":4932519
    },{
      "Sku":"650SKSH SL WH","ID":4932520
    },{
      "Sku":"650SKSH SL BL","ID":4932521
    },{
      "Sku":"650SKSH SL GLD","ID":4932522
    },{
      "Sku":"650SKSH SL MDBL","ID":4932523
    },{
      "Sku":"650SKSH SL IV","ID":4932524
    },{
      "Sku":"650SKSH SL BGY","ID":4932525
    },{
      "Sku":"650SKSH SL SKBL","ID":4932526
    },{
      "Sku":"650SKSH SL CHC","ID":4932527
    },{
      "Sku":"650SKSH SL SG","ID":4932528
    },{
      "Sku":"650SKSH SL TP","ID":4932529
    },{
      "Sku":"650QNSH SL WH","ID":4932530
    },{
      "Sku":"650QNSH SL BL","ID":4932531
    },{
      "Sku":"650QNSH SL GLD","ID":4932532
    },{
      "Sku":"650QNSH SL MDBL","ID":4932533
    },{
      "Sku":"650QNSH SL IV","ID":4932534
    },{
      "Sku":"650QNSH SL BGY","ID":4932535
    },{
      "Sku":"650QNSH SL SKBL","ID":4932536
    },{
      "Sku":"650QNSH SL CHC","ID":4932537
    },{
      "Sku":"650QNSH SL SG","ID":4932538
    },{
      "Sku":"650QNSH SL TP","ID":4932539
    },{
      "Sku":"650KGSH SL WH","ID":4932540
    },{
      "Sku":"650KGSH SL BL","ID":4932541
    },{
      "Sku":"650KGSH SL GLD","ID":4932542
    },{
      "Sku":"650KGSH SL MDBL","ID":4932543
    },{
      "Sku":"650KGSH SL IV","ID":4932544
    },{
      "Sku":"650KGSH SL BGY","ID":4932545
    },{
      "Sku":"650KGSH SL SKBL","ID":4932546
    },{
      "Sku":"650KGSH SL CHC","ID":4932547
    },{
      "Sku":"650KGSH SL SG","ID":4932548
    },{
      "Sku":"650KGSH SL TP","ID":4932549
    },{
      "Sku":"650FLSH SL WH","ID":4932550
    },{
      "Sku":"650FLSH SL BL","ID":4932551
    },{
      "Sku":"650FLSH SL GLD","ID":4932552
    },{
      "Sku":"650FLSH SL MDBL","ID":4932553
    },{
      "Sku":"650FLSH SL IV","ID":4932554
    },{
      "Sku":"650FLSH SL BGY","ID":4932555
    },{
      "Sku":"650FLSH SL SKBL","ID":4932556
    },{
      "Sku":"650FLSH SL CHC","ID":4932557
    },{
      "Sku":"650FLSH SL SG","ID":4932558
    },{
      "Sku":"650FLSH SL TP","ID":4932559
    },{
      "Sku":"650CKSH SL WH","ID":4932560
    },{
      "Sku":"650CKSH SL BL","ID":4932561
    },{
      "Sku":"650CKSH SL GLD","ID":4932562
    },{
      "Sku":"650CKSH SL MDBL","ID":4932563
    },{
      "Sku":"650CKSH SL IV","ID":4932564
    },{
      "Sku":"650CKSH SL BGY","ID":4932565
    },{
      "Sku":"650CKSH SL SKBL","ID":4932566
    },{
      "Sku":"650CKSH SL CHC","ID":4932567
    },{
      "Sku":"650CKSH SL SG","ID":4932568
    },{
      "Sku":"650CKSH SL TP","ID":4932569
    },{
      "Sku":"400TWSH SL WH","ID":4932598
    },{
      "Sku":"400TWSH SL IV","ID":4932602
    },{
      "Sku":"400TWSH SL BGY","ID":4932603
    },{
      "Sku":"400TWSH SL SKBL","ID":4932604
    },{
      "Sku":"400TWSH SL SG","ID":4932605
    },{
      "Sku":"400TWSH SL CHC","ID":4932606
    },{
      "Sku":"400TWSH SL TP","ID":4932607
    },{
      "Sku":"400QNSH SL WH","ID":4932608
    },{
      "Sku":"400QNSH SL IV","ID":4932612
    },{
      "Sku":"400QNSH SL BGY","ID":4932613
    },{
      "Sku":"400QNSH SL SKBL","ID":4932614
    },{
      "Sku":"400QNSH SL CHC","ID":4932615
    },{
      "Sku":"400QNSH SL SG","ID":4932616
    },{
      "Sku":"400QNSH SL TP","ID":4932617
    },{
      "Sku":"400SKSH SL WH","ID":4932618
    },{
      "Sku":"400SKSH SL IV","ID":4932622
    },{
      "Sku":"400SKSH SL BGY","ID":4932623
    },{
      "Sku":"400SKSH SL SKBL","ID":4932624
    },{
      "Sku":"400SKSH SL CHC","ID":4932625
    },{
      "Sku":"400SKSH SL SG","ID":4932626
    },{
      "Sku":"400SKSH SL TP","ID":4932627
    },{
      "Sku":"400KGSH SL WH","ID":4932628
    },{
      "Sku":"400KGSH SL IV","ID":4932632
    },{
      "Sku":"400KGSH SL BGY","ID":4932633
    },{
      "Sku":"400KGSH SL SKBL","ID":4932634
    },{
      "Sku":"400KGSH SL CHC","ID":4932635
    },{
      "Sku":"400KGSH SL SG","ID":4932636
    },{
      "Sku":"400KGSH SL TP","ID":4932637
    },{
      "Sku":"400FLSH SL WH","ID":4932638
    },{
      "Sku":"400FLSH SL GLD","ID":4932640
    },{
      "Sku":"400FLSH SL IV","ID":4932642
    },{
      "Sku":"400FLSH SL BGY","ID":4932643
    },{
      "Sku":"400FLSH SL SKBL","ID":4932644
    },{
      "Sku":"400FLSH SL CHC","ID":4932645
    },{
      "Sku":"400FLSH SL SG","ID":4932646
    },{
      "Sku":"400FLSH SL TP","ID":4932647
    },{
      "Sku":"400CKSH SL WH","ID":4932648
    }
  ],"@odata.nextLink":"https://api.channeladvisor.com/v1/Products?access_token=***************************************&$select=Sku%2CID&$count=true&$skip=100"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you

```
public static void Main()
{
    do
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://api.channeladvisor.com/v1/Products?access_token=*******************&$select=Sku,ID&$count=true");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var content = response.Content;

        string json = content;
    }
    while(content.Contains("odata.nextLink"))
    //rest of your code
}
```

But situation here is you need to read the value also of the nextLink. and thus you can use Newtonsoft to read it. But I see a point here is that in the nextLink it just adds `$skip=100` at the end of the URL. So I am assuming that if you have more data it would add `$skip=200` next time and thus you could have a workaround without creating the classes to read the complete JSON

```
public static void Main()
{
    string myUrl = "https://api.channeladvisor.com/v1/Products?access_token=*******************&$select=Sku,ID&$count=true";
    int cntskip = 0;
    do
    {
        if(cntskip>0)
        {
            myUrl += "$skip=" + cntskip;
        }
        var client = new RestClient(myUrl);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var content = response.Content;

        string json = content;
        cntskip += 100;
    }
    while(content.Contains("odata.nextLink"))
    //rest of your code
}
```